Mosquitto 1.6 TSL / OpenSSL error: problems getting password
When starting mosquitto (on CentOS), I am getting the following logs
06-19T14:34:55: mosquitto version 1.6.10 starting
06-19T14:34:55: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto_[org].conf.
06-19T14:34:55: Error: Unable to load server key file "/etc/pki/CA/intermediate/private/intermediate.key.pem". Check keyfile.
06-19T14:34:55: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password
06-19T14:34:55: OpenSSL Error[1]: error:0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad password read
06-19T14:34:55: OpenSSL Error[2]: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib

My Conf
# [...]
listener 8883

# Path to the PEM encoded server certificate.
# now using self signed stuff
keyfile /etc/pki/CA/intermediate/private/intermediate.key.pem
cafile /etc/pki/CA/ca.cert.pem
certfile /etc/pki/CA/intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem

tls_keyform pem
tls_engine_kpass_sha1 [hash]

Background
I am still trying to get the certificate stuff (as stated here). Basically I have created

a root key (with password)
a root certificate
an intermediate key (with password)
an intermediate certificate (signed by root, now my CA)

When I want clients (which want to connect to the broker) to use certificates, I need to sign their client certificates as far as I know. I already have one signed client certificate.
But mosquitto seems to need the key password for the intermediate key (it is using OpenSSL) and the line tls_engine_kpass_sha1 [hash] does not help.
Why not letsencrypt?
The mosquitto broker is running on a server, which has certificates, signed by Letsencrypt. But I have thought that I can sign client certificates only by myself and created my own little CA therefore. The clients should not need their certificates signed by Letsencrypt, too.
Am I on the wrong track here?
